# How to instantiate a linkedlistNode of a generic type in c#

Tags: c#, generics

For example I have a generic class KeyAndValue

```
public class KeyAndValue<T, U>
{
    public T? key { get; set; }
    public U? value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to instantiate a `LinkedListNode<KeyAndValue<int, int>>` object

```
var newNode = new LinkedListNode<KeyAndValue<int, int>>();
```

I received warning like this

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'LinkedListNode<KeyAndValue<int, int>>.LinkedListNode(KeyAndValue<int, int>)' [146]",
```

My question is how to create an object that is generic type of generic type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the existing class `KeyValuePair` instead of `KeyAndValue`. Additional you can create a constructor:

```
public class KeyAndValue<T, U>
    {
        public KeyAndValue(T key, U value)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public T? key { get; set; }
        public U? value { get; set; }
    }
```

Both is possible:

```
var keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 5);
var linkedListNode1 = new LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<int, int>>(keyValuePair);

var keyAndValue = new KeyAndValue<int, int>(0, 5);
var linkedListNode2 = new LinkedListNode<KeyAndValue<int, int>>(keyAndValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the feature in c# constructor. :D